# Cosa sono i "fornasotti"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto questa frase:

> Tagliava la legna, sapendo bene quali alberi erano da abbattere e quali da potare, raccoglieva la legna secca, e faceva **fornasotti**, fascine da forno e da piede, e stirpa e pigne, poi caricava tutto su un carretto.

Il significato di "stirpa" l'ho trovato su [questo dizionario](https://books.google.es/books?id=ONcRAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA392&lpg=PA392&dq=stirpa+bolognese&source=bl&ots=1y8RdBe59J&sig=KFIVPwtu-vABq-VY4RzoQGyKAyQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtnfbOjLvWAhWI7hoKHRWCCH8Q6AEIDzAC#v=onepage&q=stirpa%20bolognese&f=false) ("sterpi tagliati, o legname minuto da far fuoco"), ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo del significato di "fornasotti". Qualcuno di voi ne sa qualcosa?

Comment: L'unico significato che conosco di "fornasotto" è "piccola fornace", ma non mi sembra avere senso se inserito in quella frase. Potrebbe essere una figura retorica ad indicare "legna adatta per essere bruciata in un piccolo forno"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'autore si riferisce all'antico modo con cui si facevano e si vendevano le fascine di legna (cfr. [link](https://books.google.it/books?id=H_vswACDkvQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

- Le **fascine da forno** sono costituite da legna da ardere e
  ciascuna pesa 7kg.
- Le **fascine da piede** sono fascine **lunghe circa 6 piedi** e
  provenienti di solito da bosco ceduo di querce. (1 piede era circa uguale a 0.38 metri, ossia circa 38 centimetri)
- I **fornasotti** (o fornaciotti) sono le fascine di lunghezza
  inferiore di circa 4 piedi rispetto alle fascine da piede, ossia **lunghe circa 2 piedi**.
- La **stirpa**, in bolognese, equivale a [sterpi tagliati](https://books.google.it/books?id=iMAQwytfwkoC&pg=PA299&lpg=PA299&dq=stirpa+dizionario+bolognese&source=bl&ots=k80dlEoSq4&sig=UjFhiCUHXXT03gk0t-QAsvl0g-0&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI5rOl76LYAhVLtBQKHTE4BcIQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=stirpa%20dizionario%20bolognese&f=false).

I *fornasotti sono anche le piccole fornaci* a fuoco intermittente nella cosiddetta [*riviera delle fornaci*](https://books.google.it/books?id=dA8KamiwRq0C&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=riviera+delle+fornaci+sile&source=bl&ots=GQNjcBb0gv&sig=_XjkFhX3C7IM8fxId0URN1M9Qe8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1_6fP8KLYAhXJcRQKHfJSAyMQ6AEIXzAN#v=onepage&q=riviera%20delle%20fornaci%20sile&f=false) (Un tempo lungo il fiume Sile si trovavano numerose fornaci per la produzione dei laterizi, concentrate in particolare nel basso corso del fiume, dopo Treviso, tra Sant’Antonino e Musestre, tanto che questo tratto era conosciuto anche come "la riviera delle fornaci".

Gli stabilimenti erano chiamati "fornasotti" e i forni rimanevano accesi quattro o cinque giorni, in corrispondenza di ogni infornata di laterizi.
Si trovavano in aree ricche di argilla, e quando la vena del materiale si esauriva, venivano spostate in un altro luogo.)