# Cos'è una "fascina da piede"?

Tags: meaning

Si tratta di una domanda correlata a [quest'altra](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8596/707).

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto questa frase:

> Tagliava la legna, sapendo bene quali alberi erano da abbattere e quali da potare, raccoglieva la legna secca, e faceva fornasotti, **fascine** da forno e **da piede**, e stirpa e pigne, poi caricava tutto su un carretto.

Immagino che "fascine da forno" siano quelle da mettere in un forno a legna, ma non capisco il significato di "fascine da piede". Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: Non la posto come risposta perché mi è di difficile interpretazione, ma ho trovato [questo riferimento](https://books.google.it/books?id=9FIzAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA36&ots=05RlNdDyF3&dq=fascina%20da%20piede&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q&f=false): "Un carro fascine di bosco ceduo di quercie si forma di 2oo. Si appella nel bolognese _Carro di fasci di piede_ o _Carro di fornaciotti_, se la loro lunghezza inferiore a quella delle fascine di piede sia di circa piedi quattro ". Sembrerebbero quindi fascine di bosco ceduo di quercie. I _fornaciotti_ potrebbero essere i _fornasotti_.